# How to isolate one of the terms or derive an expression to arrive at one of them from given expressions

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

So I have been given 4 expressions and in three variable $a,b$ & $c$. Using these three expressions I have to isolate either of $a,b$ or $c$. However, I have not been able to come up with any equation or expression using which I could possibly isolate one of the terms. By isolate, I mean that given any expression in terms of some variables I should be able to do some operations by which I am able to get one or two variables.
For example:

If
$\;\text{eq1} = a+b+c
\\ \;\text{eq2} = a+b$

Then I must be able to obtain $a,b$ or $c$ by doing some operations and in this example it is simple subtraction.

Expressions given:

$\text{Ex1} = a + b + 2c  
\\ \text{Ex2} = c^2 + ab + 2bc + 2ca
\\ \text{Ex3} = 2abc + ac^2 + bc^2
\\ \text{Ex4} = 4((c−a)^2(c−b)^2(4c^2−4bc−4ac+9b^2−14ab+9a^2))$

Expressions I arrived at:

$\text{Ex5} = a^2 + b^2 + 2c^2
\\ \text{Ex6} = 3a^2 + 3b^2 + 4c^2 - 2ab - 4ac - 4bc$

I have not been able to arrive at any solution till now. I think the answer might be to use the expressions to derive some expression for Ex4 and divide it with that to arrive at the answer.

Edit: Wrong terminology was used. Corrected it.
Edit2: The goal is to manipulate the various equations so that after some operations are done on them the result is a,b or c while we only have the above expression to get our answer with.

Comment: How are Eq1-Eq4 equations?  I'm assuming "Eq[insert number]" is the label for the supposed equation, not a variable name.

Comment: In Eq1, $~a + b + c = ~\color{red}{\text{what ?}}$

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll edit it. I have written equations but they are just polynomials or expressions in a,b and c.

Comment: @Poke_Programmer If those were linear equations, you could eliminate variables between them and "isolate" $a=\text{something}$. But yours are not linear equations, they are polynomial ones, and eliminating variables between them will result in a *polynomial* equation for $a$ like $p(a)=0$. That's the best you can do, since polynomials of degree $\gt 4$ do not have closed form solutions in general, so you'll not be able to get an expression like $a=\text{something}$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> $$
> \begin{align}
> u &= a + b + 2c
> \\ v &= c^2 + ab + 2bc + 2ca
> \\ w &= 2abc + ac^2 + bc^2
> \\ z &= 4((c−a)^2(c−b)^2(4c^2−4bc−4ac+9b^2−14ab+9a^2))
> \end{align}
> $$

The question is not clear and can be interpreted in different ways.

- *Calculate $\,z\,$ given the values of $\,u,v,w\,$*. $\;-\;$ This can be done by eliminating $\,a,b,c\,$ between the four equations, and results (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=groebnerbasis%5B%7Ba+%2B+b+%2B+2c-u%2Cc%5E2+%2B+ab+%2B+2bc+%2B+2ca-v%2C2abc+%2B+ac%5E2+%2B+bc%5E2-w%2C4%28%28c%E2%88%92a%29%5E2%28c%E2%88%92b%29%5E2+%284c%5E2%E2%88%924bc%E2%88%924ac%2B9b%5E2%E2%88%9214ab%2B9a%5E2%29%29-z%7D%2C%7Bz%2Cu%2Cv%2Cw%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%5D)) in:
  $$
  z = -4 (27 u^3 w - 9 u^2 v^2 - 108 u v w + 32 v^3 + 108 w^2) \tag{*}
  $$
- *Solve the system for $\,a,b,c\,$*. $\;-\;$ A system with $4$ equations in $3$ unknowns is overdetermined in general. The condition for solutions to exist is that $(*)$ be satisfied, and in that case eliminating $\,b,c,\,$ between the first $3$ equations gives a sextic equation in $a$ alone ([WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=collect%5Bgroebnerbasis%5B%7Ba+%2B+b+%2B+2c-u%2Cc%5E2+%2B+ab+%2B+2bc+%2B+2ca-v%2C2abc+%2B+ac%5E2+%2B+bc%5E2-w%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cu%2Cv%2Cw%7D%2C%7Bb%2Cc%7D%5D%2Ca%5D)):
  $$
  16 a^6 - 24 a^5 u + a^4 (3 u^2 + 32 v) + a^3 (2 u^3 - 12 u v - 40 w) \\+ a^2 (3 u^4 - 18 u^2 v + 30 u w + 20 v^2) + a (-2 u^3 v + 6 u^2 w + 8 u v^2 - 36 v w) \\+ 4 u^3 w - u^2 v^2 - 18 u v w + 4 v^3 + 27 w^2 = 0
  $$

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: +1 to your posting.  Personally, if I was on medication which caused me to anonymously downvote your answer, I would subsequently be too embarrassed to step forward.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done in the latter part as I don't understand the terminology. Also I wish to have the result to be a single expression using which one can obtain either a,b or c. So can you also please tell how do we achieve it going from here. I'll also edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Poke_Programmer You can eliminate variables between polynomial equations using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Application_to_polynomial_systems) or [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Solutions_of_a_system_of_algebraic_equations). My answer does that, with two results. First one is to show that you can calculate $z$ from $u,v,w$ directly, without solving for $a,b,c$. Second one is to "isolate" $a$ into an equation that does not depend on $b,c$. It's a sextic, so there is no closed form $a=\ldots$, but you know $a$ is a root of that equation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll do some reading and try to understand it.